# bit manipulation in c giving unexpected results

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I have this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned char unit_id[] = { 0x2B, 0xC, 0x6B, 0x54}; // 8-bit (1 byte)
    unsigned long long int unit_id_val; //64-bit (8 bytes)
    int i;

    // loops 4 times
    for(i=0;i<sizeof(unit_id)/sizeof(char);i++){
      unit_id_val |= unit_id[i] << (8 * i);
    }

    printf("the unit id is %llu\n", unit_id_val);
    return 0;
}
```

hex to binary conversions:

```
0x2B = 00101011
0xC  = 00001100
0x6B = 01101011
0x54 = 01010100
```

unit_id_val is 8 bytes (I use 5 bytes for unit_id_val below to simplify things)

1) first iteration 8*0=0 so no left shift occurs:

```
00101011 = 00101011 << 0
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 |= 00101011
```

So the result should be:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00101011
```

2) Second iteration 8*1=8, so left shift all bits of unsigned char 0xC by 8:

```
00000000 = 00101011 << 8
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00101011 |= 00000000
```

So the result should be:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00101011
```

3) Third iteration 8*2=16, so left shift all bits of unsigned char 0x6B by 16:

```
00000000 = 01101011 << 16
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00101011 |= 00000000
```

So the result should be:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00101011
```

4) Fourth iteration 8*3=24, so left shift all bits of unsigned char 0x54 by 32:

```
00000000 = 01010100 << 32
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00101011 |= 00000000
```

So the result should be:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00101011
```

00101011 is 43

But when you run this program you get

1416301611

which is binary:

00010100 00010110 00110000 00010110 00010001

I am not understanding something here. I am following the precedence chart by evaluating primary expression operator () before evaluating left shift operator << before evaluating assignment operator !=. Yet I am not understanding why I get the response I get.

Comment: And *by 32* and `<< 32`?

Comment: A `printf("%x\n", unit_id[i] << (8 * i));` thrown into the loop would have shown you where your assumptions were mistaken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`00000000 = 00101011 << 8`

Ok first your second element is `0x0C` (i.e., binary `00001100` not `00101011`), so you are actually doing:

```
(unsigned char) 0x0C  << 8
```

and the result of this expression is not `0` but `0x0C00` as the bitwise `<<` operator does an integer promotion of its left operand, so it is actually equivalent to:

```
(int) (unsigned char) 0x0C << 8
```

Comment: @JohnMerlino No, the type of the result of the `<<` expression is the the type of the left operand after promotion. So here the type of `unit_id[i] << (8 * i)` is `int`, not `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 1):

You never initialize `unit_id_val`, and then you `|=` your shifted byte values into it, so whatever bits happened to be set in the uninitialized value will still be set, so your output will look like random garbage.  Add

```
unit_id_val = 0;
```

before your loop.

In addition, whenever you do ANY operation in C, the operands are always converted by the standard conversions.  In particular, that means any integer type smaller than an `int` will first be converted to `int`.  So even though `unsigned char` is only 8 bits, when you do `unit_id[i] << (8 * i)`, the 8-bit value from `unit_id[i]` will be converted to `int` (presumably 32 bits on your machine) before the shift.  There's no way to do any sort of computation on integers smaller than an `int` in C -- even if you cast them, they'll be implicitly converted back to `int`.

Comment: "Junk" or "garbage" may not be harsh enough. On Itanium, you may get signaling_not_a_value, so you must not read it (only applicable to registers)!!

Answer (score 0):

see in this line

```
unit_id_val |= unit_id[i] << (8 * i);
unit_id_val = unit_id_val | unit_id[i] << (8 * i);
```

the problem is you are using a variable which is only declare but not initialized and we know that in c uninitialized variable default value is garbage or junk. So each and every time without any doubt you will get some unpredictable value.